# How to reduce conditionality of a categorical feature using a lookup table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dimensionality-reduction

I a dataframe (df1) whose one categorical column is

```
df1=pd.Dataframe({'COL1': ['AA','AB','BC','AC','BA','BB','BB','CA','CB','CD','CE']})
```

I have another dataframe (df2) which has two columns

```
df2=pd.Dataframe({'Category':['AA','AB','AC','BA','BB','BC','CA','CB','CC','CD','CE','CF'],'general_mapping':['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C']})
```

I need to modify df1 using df2 and finally  will look like:

```
df1->> ({'COL1': ['A','A','B','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) after setting `Category` as index using [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

```
df1['COL1'] = df1['COL1'].map(df2.set_index('Category')['general_mapping'])
df1
   COL1
0     A
1     A
2     B
3     A
4     B
5     B
6     B
7     C
8     C
9     C
10    C
```

Comment: @yatu Recently started being active in `pandas` good to see you here too. :D

Comment: Haha yeh, same.

Comment: Good ansr, for some reason I assumed the resulting columns where less and a merge was needed